# For two tasks, how to run them both on each node across the whole cluster with slurm?

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing, slurm

For example:

Use mpirun to run two tasks simultaneously.

The first task uses 24 processes, with the first 12 processes running on cores 0-11 of node0 and the remaining 12 processes running on cores 0-11 of node1.

The second task uses 8 processes, with the first 4 processes running on cores 12-15 of node0 and the remaining 4 processes running on cores 12-15 of node1.

I wrote a slurm bash like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=task
#SBATCH -p part2
#SBATCH -n 32
#SBATCH -N 2
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=16
#SBATCH -o job_%j.out
#SBATCH -e job_%j.err


 mpirun -np 8 --machinefile machinefile --rankfile rankfilePy task1 &
 mpirun -np 16 --machinefile machinefile --rankfile rankfileC task2
```

The rankfilePy look like this:

```
rank 0=host0 slot=12
rank 1=host0 slot=13
rank 2=host0 slot=14
rank 3=host0 slot=15
rank 4=host1 slot=12
rank 5=host1 slot=13
rank 6=host1 slot=14
rank 7=host1 slot=15
```

Unluckily, only one task will run. Is there any wrong or how to write it?